# Form validation after after ajax callback

Tags: jquery, validation, form-submit

I try submit web form after my text field beedn validated by ajax.
but i can't protect my form (everyone can submit anyway). What i want to do is accept submiting if ajax true and not accept if ajax false:

```
$('#sample_field').change( function (){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sample_.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function validate(data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $("#sample_field").css('background-color', '#00FF00');
                return true;  
} else {    
            $("#sample_field").css('background-color', '#FF0000');

                return false;
            }
        }
    })
}); 

$("#sample_form").submit(function () {
    if(validate()){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the entire process:

```
$('#sample_field').change( function (){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sample_.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 1) {
                        $("#sample_field").css('background-color', '#00FF00');
                        $("#sample_form").submit();  
                    } else {    
                        $("#sample_field").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
                    }
                }
    });
});
```

All you have to do is make your `sample_.php` echo '1' on successful validation!